# How can I get the imagelevel of an ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview

In my app I'm using a few Imageviews with LevelListDrawables to be able to change then dynamically.

But now I want to know if I can read in which level the ImageView is stated, I set the level with setImageLevel() but there is no against hanging method to get the imagelevel.

So my question is: Is there a way to get the current imagelevel of an imageview?

Comment: Someone here told me the answer to this question.

Get the drawable from the imageview (getDrawable) and from this drawable you can get the imagelevel (getLevel).


Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do it directly to the ImageView, but you can do this

```
imageView.getDrawable().getLevel()
```

That will do the trick, for further information the offical documentation for [Drawable#getLevel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#getLevel%28%29)